# Tensorflow - get last/current value of a variable without evaluating the graph

Tags: tensorflow

I have a variable which is occasionally, manually, updated during training. For debugging though I'd like to query the value of this variable without updating it, i.e. simply getting its current value. Yet when I call `session.run(my_var)` I get the exception that I've not provided the inputs required by the graph, meaning that Tensorflow tries to re-evaluate the variable instead of simply returning its value.

Is there any way to work around this and directly query the variable's current value?

Comment: We'd need to see the code, but most likely there is something like `my_var = tf.assign(...)` at some point. You need to call `session.run` with the original variable object, then if you want to update it you can do for example `my_var_updated = tf.assign(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. What's the differnce between `my_var /= 2` and `my_var = tf.assign(my_var / 2)`?
I'm currently using the former

Comment: Right, those are actually quite different things. `my_var /= 2` is the same as `my_var = my_var / 2`, which means "the value of `my_var` divided by 2` (duh). `my_var = tf.assign(my_var / 2)` means "take the value of `my_var`, divide it by 2, then set `my_var` to that value so the next time I call `session.run` it has that value, and finally set `my_var` to the _updated_ variable value (to use for other operations within the same call to `session.run`)". So if `my_var` is 10, running the first several times will always give you 5, while the second will give you 5, 2.5, 1.25, etc.

Comment: Alright, so writing `my_var /= 2` actually assigns `my_var` a graph node for that operation without changing the actual value assigned to `my_var`. `my_var = tf.assign(my_var / 2)` would on the other hand create a node for the operation and will assign the value of the result to `my_var`. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Brilliant, great to understand this rather significant difference better, cheers for that. I'll adjust my implementation and hope this will solve the issue

Comment: Ok, problem solved indeed. Thanks a lot. Would you fancy writing a proper answer so I could set this thread to solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of variables in TensorFlow can be sometimes confusing. When you do `my_var = tf.Variable(...)` or `my_var = tf.get_variable(...)`, `my_var` is a [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) object than can hold values for the duration of a session. As is well-known, variables must be initialized before being used in a session, and their value can be changed in a call to [`tf.Session.run`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) and it will be saved for the next called.

If you do `my_var /= 2`, or `my_var = my_var / 2`, then `my_var` will not longer be a variable, but just a tensor, which is computed using the value of the variable. Importantly, this does *not* change the value of the variable created in the first place, so running this multiple times in a session will always produce the same result. In the graph, this is a "divide" node with the variable and 2 as inputs. To change the value, we could do `my_var = tf.assign(my_var / 2)`. This will also produce the "divide" node, but also another "assign" node which changes the stored value of the variable, and sets `my_var` to the newly assigned value. This last point is important, because if we just keep using the original variable object afterwards, in general, we will not be able to tell whether the original or the updated value is being used. Look at this example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    my_var = tf.Variable(0)
    my_var_2 = 2 * my_var
    my_var_upd = tf.assign(my_var, my_var + 1)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10):
        print(sess.run((my_var_2, my_var_upd)))
```

Which gave me this output in one run:

```
(0, 1)
(2, 2)
(4, 3)
(8, 4)
(8, 5)
(10, 6)
(12, 7)
(14, 8)
(16, 9)
(18, 10)
```

You may expect that `my_var_2` was the original value of `my_var` multiplied by 2, yet in one case (`(8, 4)`) it is the updated `my_var_upd` multiplied by 2. This is because the order in which TensorFlow executes nodes that do not depend on each other (like `my_var_2` and `my_var_upd`) is not deterministic - even if `my_var_2` was defined before the assignment operation. One way to fix this is using [`tf.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) to explicitly state what needs to take place before what:

```py
# ...
with tf.control_dependencies([my_var_2]):
    # Will take place only after my_var_2 is executed
    my_var_upd = tf.assign(my_var, my_var + 1)
# ...
```